# Error in equation check

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$$f(x)=2x\cdot3x-4+x-\frac64$$
$$7x=\frac{16+6}{11}$$
$$x=\frac{11}{14}\dot=0.7857$$

But substituting $\frac{11}{14}$ for x yields $-\frac{99}{98}$ instead of zero on Casio fx-991ES. Why? I have probably done numerous errors in calculations and asumptions. Please help me.

Comment: $2x\cdot 3x = 6x^2$

Comment: Also, the denominator should not be $11$.

Comment: In line 1 is a function.  In line 2 is an equation.  What is the question you are trying to answer?

Comment: do you mean $$6x+x-4-\frac{6}{4}=0$$?

Comment: Thanks @Doug M, that was the problem.

Comment: This couldn't have been the only problem because it doesn't explain the presence of $11$, which I can't explain.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your question is:

> Find the zeros of $$f(x)=2x\cdot3x-4+x-\frac64$$

DougM's comment points out your first error.  Instead, you should solve
\begin{align*}
    6x^2 + x - 4 - \frac{6}{4} &= 0 \\
    6x^2 + x - \frac{22}{4} &= 0
\end{align*}

So the equation is quadratic.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes we can take it from here

Comment: Well the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see the edited form of the question you are asking (i.e. should your function be set equal to zero?)  However, most likely the culprit when substituting back in is in misuse of the order of operations.  Take it one term at a time, especially if you are using a "cheaper" calculator.